# Polkadot JS API: Is is possible to define a custom runtime API?

Tags: polkadot-js, runtime-api

Polkadot JS Api is aware of a lot of common runtime apis in the Substrate ecosystem. The docs contain a [complete list of supported runtime apis](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/runtime). One that is missing is the PoW [Difficulty API](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sp_consensus_pow/trait.DifficultyApi.html).

Because the Polkadot JS Api is not aware of this runtime api, it logs the warning `Not decorating unknown runtime apis: 0xfbc577b9d747efd6/1`. Now, I know I can silence this warning using the [`noInitWarn` flag](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/pull/5125).

But my question is **can I tell Polkadot JS Api the signature of my runtime api so it can use the api**? I'm looking for something analogous to how you can tell it about [custom rpc endpoints](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/rpc.custom)